# delegate nested closure invokation to corresponding class

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I am trying to implement `gradle` plugin in `kotlin` that would support the structure like this

```
env {
    app ("ghc-haskell") {
        srcLink { "http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/ghc-8.0.1-x86_64-unknown-mingw32.tar.xz" }
        downloadPath { project(':').projectDir.absolutePath + "\\applications\\plugin" }
        installPath { project(':').projectDir.absolutePath + "\\applications\\plugin" }
    }
}
```

But I have a problem with inner closures like `srcLink`, `downloadPath`, `installPath`. How to delegate its invokation to corresponding `kotlin` class?

My extension looks like this

```
/**
 * Keeps all environments.
 */
open class ApplicationEnvironmentContainerExtension {
    val environs = mutableMapOf<String, ApplicationEnvironmentExtension>()

    fun app(id: String, closure : ApplicationEnvironmentContainerExtension.() -> String) : ApplicationEnvironmentExtension {
        val extension = ApplicationEnvironmentExtension()
        extension.installationId = id
        environs.put(id, extension)
        return extension
    }

    /**
     * Sub extension.
     */
    open class ApplicationEnvironmentExtension {
        var installationId = ""
        var srcLink = ""
        var downloadPath = ""
        var installPath = ""

        fun srcLink(closure: ApplicationEnvironmentExtension.() -> String) {
            srcLink = closure()
        }

        fun downloadPath(closure: ApplicationEnvironmentExtension.() -> String) {
            downloadPath = closure()
        }

        fun installPath(closure: ApplicationEnvironmentExtension.() -> String) {
            installPath = closure()
        }

        override fun toString(): String {
            return "ApplicationEnvironmentExtension(" +
                        "installationId='$installationId', " +
                        "srcLink='$srcLink', " +
                        "downloadPath='$downloadPath', " +
                        "installPath='$installPath')"
        }


    }
}
```

And when I invoke my `print` task to display list of environs it shows set only `installationId` - other fields are empty

```
open class PrintingTask :  DefaultTask() {

    @TaskAction
    fun print() {
        val extension = this.project.extensions.getByName("env")  as ApplicationEnvironmentContainerExtension

        extension.environs.forEach {
            println(it.value)
        }
    }
}
```

How delegate `closure` invokation to `ApplicationEnvironmentExtension`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue using that workaround.

For some weird reasons the parameter `closure` that I was passing into `app` method always wanted to resolve against `ApplicationEnvironmentContainerExtension` despite setting is as a closure of `ApplicationEnvironmentExtension` and even invoking it.

So I decided use brute force and create the fields - that supposed to be populated in `ApplicationEnvironmentExtension` - in `ApplicationEnvironmentContainerExtension`, fill them and set manually in the required class.

```
open class ApplicationEnvironmentContainerExtension {
    val environs = mutableMapOf<String, ApplicationEnvironmentExtension>()

    var installationId = ""
    var srcLink = ""
    var installPath = ""
    var downloadPath = ""

    fun app(id: String, closure : ApplicationEnvironmentExtension.() -> Unit) {
        val extension = ApplicationEnvironmentExtension()
        extension.installationId = id
        environs.put(id, extension)

        extension.process(closure)

        extension.setEverything(installationId, srcLink, downloadPath, installPath)
    }
}
```

As for closure I decided to set them like James Bassett suggested

```
env {
    app ("ghc-haskell") {
        srcLink = "http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/ghc-8.0.1-x86_64-unknown-mingw32.tar.xz"
        downloadPath = "$path\\applications\\plugin"
        installPath = "$path\\applications\\plugin"
    }

    app ("mongo-db") {
        srcLink = "https://fastdl.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.4.1-signed.msi"
        downloadPath = "$path\\applications\\plugin"
        installPath = "$path\\applications\\plugin"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never call the `closure` parameter in your `app` function. I think the signature of the `app` function is wrong though. It should be like this:

```
fun app(id: String, closure: ApplicationEnvironmentExtension.() -> Unit)
```

This makes the `this` in the closure refer to the `ApplicationEnvironmentExtension`. That makes the calls to `srcLink`, `downloadPath` and `installPath` hit the right object.

You then call the closure by doing this:

```
val extension = ApplicationEnvironmentExtension()
extension.closure()
```

This will populate the `ApplicationEnvironmentExtension`.

I also think the signatures of the `srcLink`, `downloadPath` and `installPath` functions are wrong. They should be defined like this:

```
 fun srcLink(closure: () -> String)
 fun downloadPath(closure: () -> String)
 fun installPath(closure: () -> String)
```

Comment: In that case it returns ` Could not find method srcLink() for arguments [build_7r01ofigr1pt144ypsds3y84p$_run_closure2_closure5_closure7@718989fa]`

Comment: What do you mean "returns"? Is that a compile error or an exception thrown at runtime?

Comment: in runtime. When I try to run some of tasks from my plugin

Comment: I missed this one when I wrote the answer, but the return type of the `closure` parameter passed to the `app` function, must be `Unit`, not `String`. Check the new signature in my edit.

Comment: Same error.  Still could not  find method `srcLink`. I thought It should properly delegate `srcLink` but it does not do that.`Could not find method srcLink() for arguments [build_7r01ofigr1pt144ypsds3y84p$_run_closure2_closure5_closure7@2c9306d3]`

Comment: Then the problem has to be somewhere else. The code works for me now.

Comment: Hm, you created gradle plugin application?

Comment: No, but the contrived example you provided in the question works for me after the fix. What kind of type is `build_7r01ofigr1pt144ypsds3y84p$_run_closure2_closure5_clos‌​ure7@2c9306d3`? Doesn't seem like a `() -> String` to me.

Comment: Could you try to add `inline` to the functions? That would make the lambda-parameters inlined as well.

Comment: Did not help. BTW you can try the project itself 
`https://github.com/lapots/gradle-app-environment-plugin` because they might be something I overlooked

Answer (score 0):

Do  you even need those functions? Can't you set `scrLink`, `downloadPath` and `installPath` as properties? i.e.

```
env {
    app ("ghc-haskell") {
        srcLink = "http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/ghc-8.0.1-x86_64-unknown-mingw32.tar.xz"
        downloadPath = project(':').projectDir.absolutePath + "\\applications\\plugin" 
        installPath = project(':').projectDir.absolutePath + "\\applications\\plugin" 
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not work either. It cannot find `srcLink` field